# Возможно ли создать поток в AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Можно ли во AS3 запустить функцию в отдельном потоке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас нет проблем с английским то вот [здесь](http://bitsofinfo.wordpress.com/2008/09/22/threads-in-as3-flex-actionscript/) очень подробно расписано что к чему.. Впринцыпе даже если имеются проблемы - код говорит сам за себя.